# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Prod_Num ='

Tags: vb.net

This Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Prod_Num ='. always shows up when I'm trying to search an item in the database. Please help me.

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim sql As String
Dim dbp As String
Dim dbs As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbp = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbs = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "/POS.accdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbp & dbs
    con.ConnectionString = dbp & dbs
    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblInventory"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgList.DataSource = dt
    txtPNum.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    dt.Clear()
    txtPNum.Text = ""
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblInventory WHERE Prod_Num =" & txtPNum.Text
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgList.DataSource = dt
    txtPName = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
    txtNOrder = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
    txtPRem = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
    txtPrice = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
    txtPNum.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: does txtPNum.Text return empty value ?

Comment: Please google parameterized queries.

Comment: you should store your value in a variable and your sql statement changes to WHERE ProdNum = " & yourvariable & " "                         OR simply do where ProdNum = '" & txtPNum.Text & "'

Comment: Sql Injection alert. This code is just begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have problem here:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    dt.Clear()
    txtPNum.Text = ""   ' <-----------------
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblInventory WHERE Prod_Num =" & txtPNum.Text
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgList.DataSource = dt
    txtPName = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
    txtNOrder = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
    txtPRem = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
    txtPrice = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
    txtPNum.Focus()
End Sub
```

**Remove this line:**

```
txtPNum.Text = ""
```

Since you always clears the `txtPNum` textbox's text before passing it to the query.

**NOTE:**

Don't forget to implement it via parameterized query. This is not a good approach.

See parameterized query examples:

[Example 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bdf8b71-1cf1-41c0-848c-4fca2c9e1ea2/faq-how-do-i-make-a-parameterized-query-in-the-database-with-vbnet)

[Example 2](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_db_parameterized_query.html)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

does txtPNum.Text contain any data?

Why don't you try checking that, because if it is empty your running SQL statement is "SELECT * FROM tblInventory WHERE Prod_Num =" which would raise that error.

Also if the Prod_Num column is integer, perhaps you should use int(txtPNum.Text) if that value is a string, this would also prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: how can it contain data... right above the SQL statement you are doing this:- txtPNum.Text = ""

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem with `txtPNum.Text` that others have pointed out, I would recommend a couple of other things:

1. Use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection.
2. Use `Using` blocks with your connection, and close the connection as soon as you are done.  In your Form_Load, for example, you open the connection and leave it open.  That is not good practice.

Example:

```
Imports System 
Imports System.Data 
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Dim con As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim dbp As String
    Dim dbs As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        dbp = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbs = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "/POS.accdb"

        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(dbp & dbs)

            con.Open()

            da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblInventory", con)
            da.Fill(dt)

            dgList.DataSource = dt
        End Using

        txtPNum.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

        dt.Clear()

        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(dbp & dbs)

            con.Open()

            da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblInventory WHERE Prod_Num = @ProdNum", con)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdNum", txtPNum.Text)
            da.Fill(dt)

            dgList.DataSource = dt         
        End Using

        txtPName = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
        txtNOrder = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
        txtPRem = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
        txtPrice = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
        txtPNum.Focus()
    End Sub
```

I would also recommend adding some Try Catch blocks to handle errors, and you may need to convert the values you're assigning to text boxes if they're something other than String.